# How to save capture video file in window 8 metro app?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, html5-video

These are code for capture video and save video. But it does not save the video content. It gives the error message

> JavaScript runtime error: Type mismatch

It comes in `saveVideo` function `copyAsync` method.

```
function captureVideo() {      
        var cam = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
        cam.videoSettings.allowTrimming = true;
        cam.videoSettings.format = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.mp4;
        cam.videoSettings.maxResolution = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMaxVideoResolution.standardDefinition;
               cam.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.video).then(function (file) {
            if (file) {
                photoBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });
                var myVideo = document.getElementById("videoId");                  
                myVideo.src = photoBlobUrl;
                myVideo.play();
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    }
function saveVideo() {
        var output;
        var input;
        var outputStream;           
        var picturesLib = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;

         picturesLib.createFileAsync("v1.mp4",
                                        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).
                                    then(function(file) {
                                        return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
                                    }).then(function (stream) {

                                        outputStream = stream;
                                        output = stream.getOutputStreamAt(0);
                                        input = photoBlobUrl;
                                        return Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output);
                                    }).then(function() {
                                        return output.flushAsync();
                                    }).done(function() {
                                        input.close();
                                        output.close();
                                        outputStream.close();

                                    });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StorageFile` typically represents a file that has already been saved. If you look at `StorageFile.Path` after taking the photo it should be something like this:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\[appname]\TempState\picture003.jpg
```

Since the file is already saved you can move or copy it to a different location like this:

```
storageFile.moveAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: no,I mean save the video .I want save the video content picturesLibrary .In my code video file is create but it is empty and also get an error.Photos are save successfully.I did it.

Comment: Using CameraCaptureUI.CaptureFileAsync creates an output file. If you are getting a zero length file or other errors you should resolve these issues first. There is no need to save the file since it is already saved. You simply need to move it or copy it to the output location.